# How can I disable resize in a View

Tags: view, resize, eclipse-rcp

My main window looks like this:

```
____________________________
|Upper View                 |
|___________________________|
|Left View|Editor|Right view|
|         |      |          |
|         |      |          |
|         |      |          |
```

and I want to make the upper view not resizable.

The Perspective.createInitialLayout is:

```
layout.addStandaloneView(URLView.ID, false, IPageLayout.TOP, 0f, layout.getEditorArea());
layout.addStandaloneView(ServicesView.ID, false, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.2f, layout.getEditorArea());
IFolderLayout folder = layout.createFolder("responses", IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.6f, layout.getEditorArea());
folder.addPlaceholder(ResponseView.ID + ":*");
folder.addView(ResponseView.ID);
layout.getViewLayout(ResponseView.ID).setCloseable(true);
```

Is there any way to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to make a view non-resizable. A possible way could be to introduce a banner to place the content of that view inside this banner. I've written some time ago a [small example](http://www.richclient2.de/2007_04_16/customizing-the-ui-in-small-rcp-projects/)

Comment: Thank you Tom. It's just what I need.